# react-bootstrap-daterangepicker initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The initial state of `react-bootstrap-daterangepicker` not updating in my project.

```
import DateRangePicker from 'react-bootstrap-daterangepicker';
...

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date()
    };
}

...

updateDates = (event) => {
    const period = event.target.value;
    let start, end = null;
    const today = new Date();
    switch(period) {
        case 'today':
            start = today;
            end = today;
            break;
        case 'thisMonth':
            start = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
            end = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);
            break;
        case 'thisWeek':
            const first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
            const last = first + 6;
            start = new Date(today.setDate(first));
            end = new Date(today.setDate(last));
            break;
        case 'thisYear':
            start = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            end = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    if(start && end) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end
        });
    }
}

...

render() {
   const sDate = this.state.startDate.toLocaleDateString();
   const eDate = this.state.endDate.toLocaleDateString();
   console.log(sDate);
   console.log(eDate);

   ...

   <DateRangePicker
    initialSettings={{ startDate: sDate.toString(), endDate: eDate.toString() }}
    onCallback={this.handleSelect}
>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
   </DateRangePicker>
   
   ...

   <select className="form-control" id="dtOption" onChange={this.updateDates}>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="today">Today</option>
    <option value="thisMonth">This Month</option>
    <option value="thisWeek">This Week</option>
    <option value="thisYear">This Year</option>
   </select>
}
```

It's odd because the console.logs in the render() method shows the updated dates after I select a date range in the dropdown, but it does not update the DateRangePicker input.

Comment: one reason I can guess is the date.toLocaleDateString() is not returning the date in expected format of DateRangePicker component. Worth trying. Best of luck

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma it is. the DateRangePicker except a string in the format mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 4):

You need to use refs to update the date ranges from outside the component. Also you can use key prop along with it and provide a unique value every time you need to update the range. This has been very well explained in the documentation here.
https://projects.skratchdot.com/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/?path=/story/daterangepicker--change-initialsettings-range-data